# How can I get messages without missing in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

i'm a newbie in Kafka. I've been testing Kafka for sending messages.

This is my situation, now.

add.java in my local VM is sending messages to kafka in my local VM regularly.

relay.java in another server is polling from kafka in my local VM and producing to kafka in another server.

While I was sending messages from kafka in my local VM to kafka in another server,

I pulled LAN cable out from my lap top. Few seconds later, I connected LAN cable to it again.

And then I found that some messages were lost while LAN cable was disconnected.

[image]

However, When the network is reconnected, I want to get all messages which are in disconnection without 
missing.

Are there any suggestions?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you use MirrorMaker (1 or 2) because it supports exactly this use case of consuming and producing to another cluster.

Secondly, `add.java` should not be dropping messages if your LAN is disconnected.

Whether you end up with dropped messages on the way from `relay.java` depends on your consumer and producer settings within there. For example, you should definitely disable auto offset commits and only commit after you have gotten a completion event and acknowledgement  from its producer action. This will result in *at least once* delivery.

You can find multiple posts about [processing guarantees in Kafka](https://medium.com/@andy.bryant/processing-guarantees-in-kafka-12dd2e30be0e)